# When I create a shareable private link and then visit it, does everyone delivering the page from the server to my computer see the link?

Tags: security, web

I mean, isn't the link basically the address that computers use to deliver the page, so how could they not see it? How can private links be secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use HTTPS, then it will be invisible.  SSL encrypts the HTTP headers as well as the page content.  The Request URL comes after GET in the HTTP header, so it's encrypted.  Your browser will encrypt the HTTP Request, and the server will provide an encrypted HTTP Response.